# blank removal in xml using libxml2

Tags: c, xml-parsing, libxml2

I have the xml file as:

```
<Config>
    <tlvid id="2">
              <type>10</type>
              <Devid>001b00100000</Devid>
    </tlvid>

    <tlvid id="3">
             <sessionid>abcd123</sessionid>
    </tlvid>
```

The code which parses the xml file is:

```
xmlNode *cur_node = NULL,*sub_node = NULL;
xmlChar *key;

cur_node = a_node->xmlChildrenNode;
while(cur_node !=NULL) {

        if((!xmlStrcmp(cur_node->name,(const xmlChar*)"tlvid"))) {
            key = xmlGetProp(cur_node,(const xmlChar*)"id");
            printf("key: %s\n ",key);
            xmlFree(key);
            sub_node = cur_node->xmlChildrenNode;

            while(sub_node !=NULL) {

            key = xmlNodeGetContent(sub_node);
            printf("subkey: %s\n ",key);
            xmlFree(key);

            sub_node = sub_node->next;
            }
        }
     cur_node = cur_node->next;
}
```

The output as:

key: 2

subkey:

subkey: 10

subkey:

subkey: 001b00100000

subkey:

key: 3

subkey:

subkey: abcd123

subkey:

I have tried xmlKeepBlanksDefault(0); adding under while loop to avoid blanks,but did not help. Can you please help me in removing these empty blanks. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just check if `key` is not empty before printing?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I have checked but still prints the same. gave if(key) before printing.

Comment: You should probably check like `if (strlen(key) != 0)` or something, as `key` is still a valid pointer.

Comment: did not work. still the same output. tried printing the strlen(key), got values as 5, 5, 4, 2 for each blank spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid processing of the text children of `cur_node` by checking [`xmlNodeIsText`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeIsText):

```
for(sub_node = cur_node->xmlChildrenNode;
    sub_node != NULL;
    sub_node = sub_node->next)
{
    if(xmlNodeIsText(sub_node)) continue;
    …
}
```

As an alternative to skipping all text nodes, you can make sure only to skip blank nodes by using [`xmlIsBlankNode`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlIsBlankNode):

```
for(sub_node = cur_node->xmlChildrenNode;
    sub_node != NULL;
    sub_node = sub_node->next)
{
    if(xmlIsBlankNode(sub_node)) continue;
    …
}
```

The two results will differ if there is non-whitespace text directly within a `<tlvid>` element.

Read [the manual for `xmlKeepBlanksDefault`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlKeepBlanksDefault) to find out the conditions required to make the parser ignore these blank nodes. Apparently you need a validating parser and a suitable DTD for this to have any effect.

Comment: The continue would need a for(;;) instead of a while(), otherwise the loopvariable would not be bumped.

Comment: @wildplasser, you're absolutely right, edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, I was about to comment on the BadStyle (IMHO) from the OP. A `for(;;) {}` loop is much more convenient, and a `if (...) continue;` to skip the unwanted stuff avoids the extra {} block + the associated indenting.